# laravel hasMany without id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm facing a really strange issue in a `hasMany` relationship,
It was not returning me anything so I started digging to try to find something

so now I have this code

> ```
>     echo $item->id ."<br />";
>     var_dump($item->menuMenuCategories()->getParent()->getKey());       echo "<br>";
>     var_dump($item->menuMenuCategories()->getParent()->getKeyName());
> ```
>
> echo "
> ";
>
> ```
>     $query = $item->menuMenuCategories()->getBaseQuery()->toSql();
>     echo $query ."<br />";
> ```

and the result is this:

> 4 string(1) "4"
>
> string(2) "id"
>
> select * from `GS_menu_menu_categories` where
>   `GS_menu_menu_categories`.`deleted_at` is null and
>   `GS_menu_menu_categories`.`item_id` = ?
>
> select * from `GS_menu_menu_categories` where
>   `GS_menu_menu_categories`.`deleted_at` is null and
>   `GS_menu_menu_categories`.`item_id` = ?

Can you see the item_id = ? ??

That why it is not returning me anything..

My model has the relationship defined this way:

> ```
> public function menuMenuCategories(){
>     return $this->hasMany('MenuMenuCategory','item_id');
> }
> ```

Any idea on why it isn't working? I have the hasMany relationship in a thousand places and never had this problem..

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have provided everything properly; for example, `item_id` should be in the related table `GS_menu_menu_categories` and it should contain an `id` primary key, or you may specify both if they are different, i.e:

```
class Item extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'items';

    public function menuMenuCategories(){
        // if GS_menu_menu_categories has "the_id" instead of "id" as pk
        return $this->hasMany('MenuMenuCategory','item_id', 'the_id');
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
$item = Item::with('menuMenuCategories')->find(1); // the item with id 1
```

Use following to access the related collection of models

```
$menuMenuCategories = $item->menuMenuCategories;

$item->menuMenuCategories->first(); // get the first one
$item->menuMenuCategories->get(1); // get the second one
$item->menuMenuCategories->get(2); // get the third one
```

Don't use this:

```
    $item->menuMenuCategories()
```

So, for example, in a view (`non-blade`):

```
foreach($item->menuMenuCategories as $category) {
    echo $category->propertyName;
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for you answer, the problem was exactly what you mentioned, to use $item->menuMenuCategories instead of $item->menuMenuCategories()!